# Unscoping eagerly-loaded polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading

I have a gallery model with a default scope that `includes(:galleriable)`

when I do

```
OtherModel.unscoped.includes(:linkable)...
```

when linkable could be a Gallery model, it includes `:galleriable`, which I want to avoid since I won't use it.

is there a way to unscope the eagerly-loaded association?